# Move wildscard files from Linux to Windows via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

Forgive me if this question already exists, but I cannot find one that is exactly like this:

We currently have a linux system which produces `*.dat` files and are saved directly on the server.
We then have a script running on a separate Windows server which connects to the server using psftp, copied them and deletes them with the following commands:

```
mget *.dat
del *.dat
```

However the issue with this is we are finding files get lost and completely disappear. Perhaps files are generated in the time between the mget and the del command is run - leading to files being deleted before they are copied first.

I am happy for any solution, but unsure as to how to best write this script:

- Delete only the files that have definitely been copied
- Move the files to an archive directory on the linux server after being copied so they cannot be copied again.

I have tried using `mv` but apparently this does not work with wildcard expressions. Therefore I think I need to generate a list of files to move / copy first using `mls` or similar and then run the commands with a loop - but not entirely sure how to work that into a script which runs in task scheduler.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`mv` with a wildcard should work, if used properly.

However using `mv *.dat …` to move files to another remote directory *after* being copied is as flawed as your original approach.

Move the files *first*. The destination directory will become your list of files. Get the files from it.

```
mkdir transfer
mv *.dat transfer/
mget transfer/*.dat
del transfer/*.dat
rmdir transfer
```

Note this simple snippet is still dumb, commands may fail, so don't let the code continue on errors (don't use `pstfp -be …`). Especially if `mget` fails and the code continues, `del` will lead to data loss. Nevertheless the issue with files generated in between is solved: between `mget` and `del` nothing is added to the `transfer` directory.

There's another issue. Whatever process generates a `.dat` file on the server, it should write to a temporary file that is not matched by `*.dat`, finish writing and only then *atomically* move the file to the final pathname. Otherwise `mv`, `mget` and `del` may work on an *incomplete* file (in Linux you can move or delete a file that is open and being written to). Hopefully the process is smart enough to work this way. If it's not smart enough, the issue is not easily solvable. If it is smart enough, the sole existence of a `.dat` file means the file is complete.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will give this a go, but I don't think mv wildcards do work with psftp, If they do, that would be great.  Much appreciated on the information about copying an incomplete file. I will make some changes to the Linux script to change the name to .dat only after the file has been completely copied.

Answer (score 0):

Some minor details are missing but I'll make assumptions. In particular, this process is being driven by a batch file I assume, and looks something like this...

```
@echo off
psftp user@host -b mypsftpcmds.dat
```

and mypsftpcmds.dat would of course have the commands you provided in your question...

```
mget *.dat
del *.dat
```

I think to make this more robust there are a few approaches. One simple solution that comes to mind is to only delete files on the Linux host that you know for sure exist on the Windows host. To do this I would perform the "mget *.dat" separately, then in the batch file run a "psftp del" for each *.dat file found in the Windows directory.

In my example below, I create a temp file containing the psftp delete command for each individual *.dat file found on the Windows host. Then "psftp -b" is called using that temp file.

For example, your batch file might look like ...

```
@echo off
psftp user@host -b mgetCommandOnly.dat
FOR %%F IN (*.dat) DO (
    echo del %%F > tmpfile.dat
    psftp user@host -b tmpfile.dat
)
del tmpfile.dat
```

and your first psftp commands file ("mgetCommandOnly.dat" in my example) would only have one line...

```
mget *.dat
```

This solution probably needs additional tuning. For example, if you always copy into the same Windows directory, then old *.dat files might exist from previous days. The "FOR %%F" command would process these files as well, meaning that it will attempt to delete files of the same name from the Linux host.

For example, on Monday let's say Linux contains three *.dat files

```
aaa.dat
bbb.dat
ccc.dat
```

.. and you batch process successfully pulls those files to Windows and deletes them from Linux. But if on Tuesday Linux only has two *.dat files...

```
aaa.dat
bbb.dat
```

.. your batch file will grab these two files no problem. But ccc.dat still exists on Windows from Monday! The means the "FOR %%F" loop will attempt to remove aaa.dat, bbb.dat (successfully) and ccc.dat (fails). It fails on ccc.dat because on Tuesday ccc.dat never existed on the Linux host.

This will result in a file-does-not-exist error message but I don't think it will cause the batch file to abort. If you're willing to ignore error messages like this, then you don't need to worry about making the batch file more intelligent in this respect.

But if you want avoid this you might need to (if it is an acceptable solution) delete all old *.dat files from your Windows directory prior to running the mget command. Or at least backup the old *.dat files and store them elsewhere.

In addition, my solution does not guarantee the copied files are identical to the original files. They could in theory be corrupted. Not likely, but if you really want to guarantee an exact copy, my solution doesn't address that issue. If you need an idea for that, let me know and I'll post a way to do it. Or if you try it yourself, just be aware as to whether you're transferring the files in binary or text mode. If the latter, the file sizes will most likely be different, as the Linux line endings (newlines) will be replaced with carriage return/linefeed (CR/LF) pairs on the Windows side.

Another, slightly more complicated, solution would be to run a psftp dir command first, saving the results to a local temp file, and then doing an individual get and del for each file found in the temp file. This would probably be even more robust and precise than my original solution. I can suggest a way to do this if you're interested.

Finally ... as to whether files are created between the time you run mget *.dat and del *.dat in your original solution, depending on how many files and how big the files are, the mget *.dat and del *.dat commands might be separated by a significant time period and it is possible new files appear between the two commands. This would result in del *.dat deleting *more* files than mget *.dat retrieved - that is quite possibly what you've been running into.

My solutions above will not delete any file on Linux that has not already been copied over to Windows. That is the most important advantage of my solution.

What my solution does not address is whether you want to pull any new *.dat files that appeared after the mget *.dat and before the end of the batch file.

A simple approach to this would be to run the script twice in a row. Any new *.dat files would be picked up during the second invocation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your extremely thoughtful reply to me here. I definitely think the only deleting what is copied over is a good step. I will give some of your and Kamil's code a go, and get back to you with my solution.